Decimal precision error for token in phantom
I am creating a dApp, which swaps tokens from a liquidity pool( X token and SOL), the problem is with the X token, whenever I enter the amount e.g. 1000, I apply decimal precision. i.e 1000 * 1_000_000, and I send the swapInstruction to the wallet, the amount that is shown in my phantom wallet is 999.9992 I am unable to understand why is this happening, on the other hand, when  I am running the same code in my ts-script, swapping the same token and same amount from the same liquidity pool, sending the transaction from my terminal, it's working, and there's no value fluctuation, is this a phantom bug or something I am missing?
